# Haskell local function Is not in scope

Tags: function, haskell, where-clause, local

The following function is supposed to return the sum of all the polynomials in a list having a polynomial as a list of floats. *(ie: 4x²+2x+1 would be `[4,2,1]` and 5x⁵+x+2 `[5,0,0,0,1,2]`)*

```
psum :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
psum (x1:x2:xs) = psum (binpsum (x1, x2)):xs
psum x = x
    where   binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y:binpsum (xs, ys) 
            binpsum (x) (y:ys) = x+y:ys
            binpsum (x:xs) (y) = x+y:xs
```

I'm getting

```
 Not in scope: ‘binpsum’
```

It's the first time I work with haskell so I'd guess there's something wrong in the way I use `binpsum (x1, x2)` since I can't find anything wrong in the where clause.

Thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's probably an indentation problem. Last two lines need to be indented as far as the one above. (I.e., `binpsum` needs to line up on all three lines.)

Comment: Try fixing indentation so that the three `binpsum` lines start on the same column.

Comment: Sorry, pasting the code made the indentation like that, my code has the indentation like I just edited it and gets that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The `where` clause only provides bindings to the equation directly above (or to the left) of it.** You can fix this by moving it up, under the first of equation of `psum` where it is actually used.

Other than that, there are various additional misunderstandings that I'm seeing in your code:

1. When a function is defined like `f x y`, it must be called like that too (not like `f (x, y)`).
2. If you want to pattern match against a single item in a list, you must enclose the item in square brackets to indicate that it is indeed the item that you want to bind, and not the list itself.
3. If an argument to a function is a expression of more than one word/symbol, you usually need to enclose it in brackets (e.g. `f (a + b)` instead of `f a + b`).

Here is a version of your code that compiles:

```
psum :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
psum (x1:x2:xs) = psum (binpsum x1 x2 : xs)
    where binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y : binpsum xs ys
          binpsum [x] (y:ys) = x+y : ys
          binpsum (x:xs) [y] = x+y : xs
psum [x] = x
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function `binpsum` is only in the scope of the second definition. You can rewrite it one of these ways:

```
psum :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
psum (x1:x2:xs) = psum (binpsum x1 x2):xs
  where 
    binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y : binpsum xs ys
    binpsum (x) (y:ys) = x+y:ys
    binpsum (x:xs) (y) = x+y:xs
psum x = x
```

or better:

```
psum :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
psum lst = case lst of
   x1:x2:xs -> psum (binpsum x1 x2) : xs
   _        -> lst
 where 
   binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y : binpsum xs ys
   binpsum (x) (y:ys) = x+y : ys
   binpsum (x:xs) (y) = x+y : xs
```

**EDIT:** After some correction in your code, though, it would look like this: (I just made it compile, I don't know if it does what you intended)

```
psum :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
psum lst = case lst of
    x1:x2:xs -> psum $ binpsum x1 x2 : xs
    [x]      -> x
  where
    binpsum [x] (y:ys)    = x + y : ys
    binpsum (x:xs) [y]    = x + y : xs
    binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys) = x + y : binpsum xs ys
```

Note that `binpsum (x:xs) (y:ys)` is now at the end as `[3]` would match `(x:xs)` with `x = 3` and `xs = []`.

Comment: I think that `binpsum (x1, x2)` should be changed to `binpsum x1 x2` as the type of `binpsum` according to its definition is `[Float] -> [Float] -> [Float]`

Comment: Yes, I just edited. I just rearrange the code, didn't try to run it to be honest. Cheers.

Comment: You both are right. However now I get a `parse error on input ':'` on the second ':' of `(x1:x2:xs)` . Shouldn't that work for getting two lists and the rest?

Comment: Just made your code compile (see the edited answer), I don't know if it works though as I haven't looked into that.